# -[NSDate timeIntervalSinceDate:] returns very small number on GCC 4.2, but works as expected on LLVM-GCC 4.2 on iOS4.3 Simulator

Tags: objective-c, gcc, llvm, llvm-gcc

On iOS 4.3 Simulator, the following code returns a very small number: `1e-700` on GCC 4.2, but works as expected on LLVM-GCC 4.2.  Any ideas?

```
NSDate *selectedDate = self.datepicker.date; // guaranteed to be before now
NSTimeInterval interval = [nowDate timeIntervalSinceDate:selectedDate];
```

these values change with each run, but here is an example set of output

selectedDate: `1981-06-02 16:27:34 +0000`

nowDate: `2011-08-03 05:18:36 +0000`

interval: `5.489011535689859e-277`

running `[nowDate timeIntervalSinceDate:selectedDate]` in GDB: `952001462.97236204` (this is my expected value)

Comment: How are you determining that `interval` contains 1e-700 on GCC 4.2?

Comment: I print it in GDB with the following command:
p (NSTimeInterval) interval

Comment: Can you show the values of selectedDate and nowDate when you're doing this test?

Comment: I retested against iOS 5.1 and can't replicate the issue

Comment: @HeathBorders It sounds like your question resolved itself. Please mark it as closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a bug with GCC. I think you should fill a bug report and see what Apple has to say.

Comment: I retested with iOS 5.1, and can't replicate the issue.

Answer (score -1):

The unexpected value is an overflow.