# NSDate turning into NSNumber MYSTERY

Tags: ios, nsdate

I'm working in iOS 4.3 & iOS 5 with automatic reference counting.  I declare a NSDate object in my interface:

```
NSDate *fingerprintsDate;
```

Later, I set that NSDate - using the debugger and stepping through it has the value I'd expect:

```
fingerprintsDate = [NSDate date];
```

Finally, I try to get the time from the date:

```
if (fingerprintsDate == nil || [fingerprintsDate timeIntervalSinceNow] > 6)
```

And that's where it crashes with unrecognized selector:  "2012-01-18 23:07:46.662 Netapporter[473:707] -[NSCFNumber timeIntervalSinceNow]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x194490"

According to the debugger, my dear NSDate reads: "fingerprintsDate = (NSCFNumber *) 0x194490 139"  - when I print description it reads:  "{value = +139.0000000000, type = kCFNumberFloat32Type}"

I'm not doing anything else w/ fingerprintsDate anywhere else in the code - but somehow it's turning into an NSNumer...  Any ideas how to stop it?

Comment: There must be some other code "in between" that is doing it (namely, writing over your date). Could you post some more code?

Comment: Why would you check if the date is nil or over 6?  Check it with this for me: if ([[myNum className] isEqualToString:@"NSCFNumber"]) {NSLog:(@"is number)}

Comment: There is no problem with the code that is showing here . but after reading the bug report might be you are trying to using the return value of "timeIntervalSinceNow" method at wrong place(parameter) , actually "- (NSTimeInterval)timeIntervalSinceNow " return the float value.

Comment: Thanks guys: Dasblinkenlight:  There's a method "start" where I call "fingerprintsDate = nil", I've tried it with / without this no change.  There's nowhere else in the code where fingerprintsDate appears at all.     CodaFi: I'm trying to show an on-screen animation of how to interact with the app.  I would like to trigger it when touchesEnd without a successful interaction as long as it's not already running - the anim takes about 6 seconds.      Kulss: Thanks, just tested it with (float)[fingerprintsDate timeIntervalSinceNow] but it still occurs.  Looks like NSTimeInterval is just a double.

Comment: Adding a new wrinkle - when I turn fingerprintsDate into a property and replace everything with self.fingerprintsDate it works

Comment: I've also seen this crash on the wild.

Answer (score 0):

[NSDate date] returns a non-retained value (or weak if you're using arc), so it most likely got released somewhere between that assignment and calling [fingerprintsDate timeIntervalSinceNow]. When you assign it to a retained (strong) property, it's being retained.

Comment: ARC defaults locals to strong. I don't think that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you debugging with GBD, compiling with GCC? Could be related to my question: [-[NSDate timeIntervalSinceDate:] returns very small number on GCC 4.2, but works as expected on LLVM-GCC 4.2 on iOS4.3 Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6918350/9636)

Comment: And how would that explain `[fingerprintsDate timeIntervalSinceNow]` crashing with a claim that `figerprintsDate` is an NSNumber and not an NSDate?

Comment: It doesn't directly. It's just some other weird behavior I saw with similar APIs on iOS4.3.